# Create an array using forEach that has all the usernames

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is an array and I want to use foreach to create an array using forEach that has all the usernames with a "!" to each of the usernames

```
const array = [
 {
  username: "john",
  team: "red",
  score: 5,
  items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
 },
 {
  username: "becky",
  team: "blue",
  score: 10,
  items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
 },
{
  username: "susy",
  team: "red",
  score: 55,
  items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]
 },
 {
  username: "tyson",
  team: "green",
  score: 1,
  items: ["book", "pen"]
},

];
```

What i try in JS:

```
const double=[];
const newArray = array.forEach(array[i].username)=>{
double.push(array[i].username+"!");
});
console.log(double);
```

What i got in error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

What is the right way to use foreach to  access the object in the array?

Comment: Using `forEach` in this case is wrong, use map instead `const userNames = array.map(element => element.username)`

Comment: sorry,It's my homework request.They also want me to use map.I'll take your  advice.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `forEach` like so (note using `var` not `const` because you can't modify `const`):

```js
const array = [{
    username: "john",
    team: "red",
    score: 5,
    items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "becky",
    team: "blue",
    score: 10,
    items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "susy",
    team: "red",
    score: 55,
    items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "tyson",
    team: "green",
    score: 1,
    items: ["book", "pen"]
  },
];

var double = [];
array.forEach(person => double.push(person.username + "!"));

console.log(double);
```

However, it's much simpler to use `map`:

```js
const array = [{
    username: "john",
    team: "red",
    score: 5,
    items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "becky",
    team: "blue",
    score: 10,
    items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "susy",
    team: "red",
    score: 55,
    items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "tyson",
    team: "green",
    score: 1,
    items: ["book", "pen"]
  },
];

var double = array.map(person => person.username + "!");

console.log(double);
```

Comment: @Jacky I've fixed it now, does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [destrcturing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const array = [{username: "john",team: "red",score: 5, items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]},{username: "becky",team:"blue",score: 10,items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]},{username: "susy",team: "red",score: 55,items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]},{username: "tyson",team: "green",score: 1,items: ["book", "pen"]},];

let op = array.map(({username})=>  username + '!')

console.log(op)
```

If you want to use your code removing some mistakes

1. You can't change a value of variable once you define it constant.
2. `const newArray = array.forEach....` `forEach` don't return a value so this assignment is of no use.
3. `array.forEach(array[i].username)=>...` this is a syntax error. you need to use it either `array.forEach((array[i].username)=>...` or `array.forEach(array[i].username => ....`

You can see the changed code in below code snippet.

```js
const array = [{username: "john",team: "red",score: 5, items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]},{username: "becky",team:"blue",score: 10,items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]},{username: "susy",team: "red",score: 55,items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]},{username: "tyson",team: "green",score: 1,items: ["book", "pen"]},];

let double=[];
array.forEach(input=>{
double.push(input.username+"!");
});
console.log(double);
```

Answer (score 0):

Originally you were on right path, but syntax a little wrong.

```
const array = [{
    username: "john",
    team: "red",
    score: 5,
    items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "becky",
    team: "blue",
    score: 10,
    items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "susy",
    team: "red",
    score: 55,
    items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "tyson",
    team: "green",
    score: 1,
    items: ["book", "pen"]
  },
];

const doubleNew = [];
const doubleThis = array.forEach(person => {
  doubleNew.push(person.username + `!`);
})

console.log(doubleNew);
```

Comment: Please have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) help page about how to format code properly.